# Understanding Admonitions in Julia

Tags: julia, markdown, comments

I try to understand [Admonitions in Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/#Admonitions).

When I try:

```
julia> !!! warning "test"
ERROR: syntax: extra token """ after end of expression
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:1
```

What am I doing wrong? It is not working either in .jl files

```
julia> include("main.jl")
[ Info: Loading JuMP
[ Info: Loading Gurobi
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: syntax: extra token "test" after end of expression
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admonitions are only valid in markdown, for example in an `md`-string:

```
julia> using Markdown

julia> md"""
       !!! warning "test"
           This is a test warning.
       """
```